# android panel can not get focus

Tags: android, focus

I have two layouts: A and B.

Both A and B are RelativeLayout.

They are in a FrameLayout. B is hidden behind A.

When I click B, it is pulled out from A, and I click B again, it hides.

**Now the question is: After B is pulled out, why can't I click the
buttons and EditTexts on it? Panel B can not get focus.**

```
Animation showAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoginActivity.this, R.anim.login_show);
showAnimation.setFillAfter(true);               
doctorLoginLayout.startAnimation(showAnimation);
doctorLoginLayout.setFocusable(true);               
doctorLoginLayout.requestFocus();
doctorLoginLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have known the reason.
I have changed the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an animation listener, and write these lines onAnimatedEnd

```
Animation showAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoginActivity.this, R.anim.login_show);
showAnimation.setFillAfter(true);    
showAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                 doctorLoginLayout.setFocusable(true);               
                 doctorLoginLayout.requestFocus();
                 doctorLoginLayout.setClickable(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
doctorLoginLayout.startAnimation(showAnimation);
```

But this line should be enough to achieve what you want to:

```
doctorLoginLayout.requestFocus();
```